# c# Setting new registry value only if registry value name already exists

Tags: c#, registry, setvalue

My problem is that when I am using the Registry.SetValue I only want it to update an existing value. If a value name is entered that does not exist, I do not want to create it. I have variable data that the user enters, so I can not hardcode paths within my code.

My Code for my Set

```
    public class SetRegistryValue : CodeActivity
{
    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> kpath { get; set; }

    public InArgument<string> txtName { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> kvaluename { get; set; }

    [RequiredArgument]
    public InArgument<string> kvalue { get; set; }

    //This will set the value of an key that is defined by user
    protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
    {

        string KeyPath = this.kpath.Get(context);
        string KeyValueName = this.kvaluename.Get(context);
        string KeyValue = this.kvalue.Get(context);
        string KeyName = Path.GetDirectoryName(KeyPath);
        string KeyFileName = Path.GetFileName(KeyPath);
        string fullKeyPath = KeyName + "\\" +  KeyFileName;

        Registry.SetValue(fullKeyPath, KeyValueName, KeyValue, RegistryValueKind.String);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure we will help you out, Could you please explain what you want clearly .if possible please provide some example.

Comment: @sudhakar like grant said bellow I want to get the value of the value name. I want to get look at the value name within the registry, if it is there change the value to whatever new value is provided in the activity. But if the value name is not in the path, do not do the setvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [Registry.GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

> Retrieves the value associated with the specified name, in the specified registry key. If the name is not found in the specified key, returns a default value that you provide, or null if the specified key does not exist.

If you want to test whether the `keyName` exists, test for null:

```
var myValue
  = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\missing_key", "missing_value", "hi");

// myValue = null (because that's just what GetValue returns)
```

If you want to test whether the `valueName` exists, test for your default value:

```
var myValue
  = Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\valid_key", "missing_value", null);

// myValue = null (because that's what you specified as the defaultValue)
```

---

If the path could be invalid, you could try surrounding it with a `try/catch` block:

```
try
{
    var myValue = Registry.GetValue( ... );  // throws exception on invalid keyName

    if (myValue != null)
        Registry.SetValue( ... );
}
catch (ArgumentException ex)
{
    // do something like tell user that path is invalid
}
```

Comment: Think is what I thought to use at first, but I can not control within the code the path of the getvalue, which is when I error out. You can see my set activity from above code. My get activity looks similar but obviously a get activity.

Comment: Looks like that will do it. Will full test on Monday but if you do not here back from me, it worked. Looks like it will, I tried something similar but was not declaring as var...big mistake on my part. p.s. noticed your from cleveland also...GO BROWNS